# Install Drupal with MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: database

Is it possible in any ways to connect Drupal 6.x to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008? I am really struggling to find a way out.

please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The [requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements) clearly states that the supported databases in Drupal 6 are "MySQL 4.1 or higher, PostgreSQL 7.1."

You would have to write the database support yourself to get this working.

Drupal 7 does support MS SQL Server however.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6 **cannot** use MSSQL as the storage engine

Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 **can** do so by means of the SQL Server Driver for Drupal:

https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv

The Drupal 8 version of the driver is a complete rewrite of the Drupal 7 driver and works like a charm.

To get it working you need to setup some other things, such as the MSSQL PDO  PHP extension, a detailed tutorial can be found here:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-windows-and-sql-server

> It's also still not likely to work as well as it does in MySQL.

I must object to this statement. We have found that MSSQL is better suited for big clusters and monster scaling thanks to features such as in-memory tables, always-on, etc. If you are using Drupal for brochureware this is meaningless though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Drupal 7 has an database abstraction layer that makes it possible to support MSSQL, but you still need modules like [SQLSRV](http://drupal.org/project/sqlsrv) for it to work. It's also still not likely to work as well as it does in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

First use Godaddy as it only a short time with there help to setup the latest version of Drupal. I use 2008R2 with Drupal but you do need to write code to connect..